# How to use scroll in javascript without using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

How to add scroll in JavaScript without using jquery? I just want to add scroll effect on a div without using jquery to make the code efficient.

Comment: Search before asking any question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your answer

```
document.queryselector("#btn").addEventListener("onscroll", displayDiv);
```

Answer (score 0):

I searched and found another way to call it `object.onscroll = function(){myScript};` and it also worked